# Vim searching ruby with symbol

Tags: ruby, regex, search, vim, replace

I'm trying to take a string, copy it to a register and then do a search replace on it. ergo `@user = User.find(params[:id])` I keep getting `E486 Pattern not found`

I am pretty sure I could find a way to escape the appropriate characters out and make it work that way. Which is fine, but in this case I am loading the string from register "a".
`:%s/<c-r>a/foo/gc`

Is there a way to some how escape the whole string to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the regex mode to very nomagic by adding a `\V` to the pattern. In this mode the only special character is the backslash. If you don't have any of them you can just insert the register normally. (Or escape them manually)

```
:%s/\V<c-r>a/foo/gc
```

If you want to automatically escape them, you could probably pass the register to the escape function with the expression register

```
:%s/\V<c-r>=escape(@a, '\')<cr>/foo/gc
```

Relevant help section would be `:h \V` and `:h c_CTRL-R_=`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would get a [visual star](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search) plugin (there are few out there). There is a nice Vimcast about this: [Search for the selected text](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-for-the-selected-text/). I would then use that with the `:s//foo/gc` to accomplish your goal.